# bash script: how can we use nested if in a for loop

Tags: bash, scripting

```
#! /bin/bash

count=1
step=(a b)

for x in 0 1
do
    if [[ $count != '0' ]]; then
        if [[ ${step[x]} = "a"]]; then
            echo "Python test ($count)"
        else
            echo "stress test"
        fi
    fi
done
```

I get the following error

```
syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'
line 20: syntax error near `;
line 20: `        if [[ ${step[x]} = "a"]]; then'
```

Why?

Comment: How does line 9 get to be line 20?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a space between `"a"` and the `]]` in the second `if`.

More technically, `[[` and `]]` have to be separate tokens, and bash's parser doesn't separate tokens on quotes or most punctuation.

I believe your original code for the line is equivalent to `if [[ ${step[x]} = "a]]"; then` if that makes the issue more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if [[ ${step[x]} = "a"]]; then
```

to

```
if [[ ${step[$x]} = "a" ]]; then
```

i.e. <strike>use `$x` instead of `x` and</strike> add some space after the last parameter.

Update: You don't need to precede variables with a `$` sign in array subscripts (also within double parenthesis `(( ))` or after the `let` keyword).

Comment: Yep, the `x` in array access is ok, but why?

Comment: yeah it worked for me without the $, the issue was that i did not have a space after "a" ] .

Comment: yeah it worked for me without the $, the issue was that i did not have a space after "a" ] .
thanks

Comment: @Slomojo: Array indices are an arithmetic context which doesn't require dollar signs. Similarly: `((a++))` and `echo $((a * b))`